# Why did git commit hunks of a file not staged to the index?

Tags: git

I do not want to stage all changes within a single file, `myfile`, to the index.  Rather, I want to select hunks of changes within `myfile` to stage to the index.

`git add --patch`  seemed like the command and option I needed.  See my attempted use of the command/option below.

```
100 % git status -s
 M myfile

101 % git add --patch myfile

102 % git status -s
MM myfile
```

So far so good.

`Command 100` outputs an `M` with a leading space, denoting all hunks to `myfile` are unstaged.

`Command 101` Allowed me to use the `y` option to select the hunks I wanted to stage and used the `n` option to not stage a hunk.

`Command 102` outputs an additional `M` before the `M` with the leading space.  I assumed this denoted the set of hunks I staged to the index in `Command 101` and the rest of the hunks are not staged to the index.

I then committed and was surprised `git` seemed to commit all hunks, instead of just the hunks I selected.  See commands below.

```
103 % git commit

104 % git status -s
Nothing to stage
```

The above output after executing `line 104` surprised me.  I expected the output after executing `line 104` to be the following, instead.

```
104 % git status -s
 M myfile
```

Why did `git` commit all changes within the file and not just the hunks I staged to the index?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue and my `git commit -m "xxx"` command only committed the hunks I chose. Can you provide a [mcve] including all commands and such?

Comment: I just repeated your procedure with a random repository and it worked as expected. It could be helpful if you could undo your commit and redo the `git add` but then run `git status` (without `-s`), `git diff` and `git diff --cached` to see what is going on exactly.

Comment: Do you have a pre-commit hook? If so, what is in it? Do you have a post-commit hook?

Comment: @torek Yes, I have both pre-commit hooks and a post-commit hooks.  I am searching for any code in the hooks that might manually force a git add of all files.  Anything else or in particular I should look for in these hooks?

Comment: @torek That was the issue.  I had a pre-commit hook which made some validity checks on every file staged to the index.  If the checks passed, then the hook does a ```git add``` of the file. Commented the hook out and everything works.

Comment: That's actually a somewhat common bug in various hooks, caused by folks writing hooks without understanding the actual commit model. It interferes with `git add -p` which is of course exactly how you hit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586640/why-did-git-commit-hunks-of-a-file-not-staged-to-the-index#comment105339843_59586640) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586640/why-did-git-commit-hunks-of-a-file-not-staged-to-the-index#comment105339890_59586640), the problem in this case was a bad hook.  The pre-commit hook for this particular repository runs `git add` inappropriately.

As a general rule, writing a good pre-commit hook is hard *unless* the hook simply *inspects* the commit.  Even then the inspection code should be careful to use what is in the index (staging area), rather than what is in the work-tree.